# Weird file creation timestamps

Tags: c#, file

Well, I create numerous files using the `FileInfo.Create()` method, then after some time has passed, I look for all files that are created on that date.

```
oCurrentFile 
    = new FileInfo(oFileRegion.Directory.FullName + "\\" + _traceFilePrefix 
                    + sIdentifier + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss.ffff") + _traceFileExt);
FileStream fs = oCurrentFile.Create(); fs.Close();
```

This worked very well for days! Now recently, I tried to gather all the files that were created yesterday.

```
IEnumerable<FileInfo> oldFiles =
    (from oldFile in oldFiles
    where oldFile.CreationTime.DayOfYear == DateTime.Now.Substract(new TimeSpan(1,0,0,0).DayOfYear
    orderby oldFile.CreationTime ascending
    select oldFile)
```

When I looked up the number of files using `.Count()` the surprise was big: **0**.

So I checked why it didn't found any files and noticed, that all my files had the following creation date:

01.01.1601 00:00:00.000

What the heck? What causes such a strange behaviour? And why Windows stopped getting creation dates right out of nowhere?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same behavior for files which FileInfo didn't think existed. Make sure that the file exists, and that it was created BEFORE the FileInfo object. Otherwise, you need to call FileInfo.Refresh() in order for the state data within the FileInfo object to be updated.